# Update field in each document in a mongo db with list of all id's of documents matching the filter query

Tags: typescript, mongoose

As the title implies, I am trying to update a field in all documents matching the filter criteria with a list of all ids of these documents. I can do this in two rounds, but I am hoping there is a way to combine this in one.

I've tried various combinations of below code, but it does not seem to work, it claim to not know what siblings is. I am using this through aws and I believe documentDb v4.0.

Any ideas how to make this work?

EDIT: documents look something like this:

```
{
  id: string,
  date: string,
  series: {
    id: string,
    slug: string,
    title: string,
  }
}
```

The desired outcome:

```
{
  id: string,
  date: string,
  series: {
    id: string
    slug: string,
    title: string,
    siblings: array of {id, date}
  }
}

  const publishedDocuments = await Document.updateMany(
  {
    "series.id": document.sys.id,
    status: "Published",
  },[{ $addFields: { siblings: {$concatArrays: ["$siblings", {$objectToArray: {id: "$id", date: "$date"}}]} },
   { $set {
    "series": {
      id: document.sys.id,
      title: document.fields?.title?.["en-US"] ?? "",
      slug: document.fields?.slug?.["en-US"] ?? "",
      siblings: siblings
    },
   }
  }],
);
```

Comment: Show some sample input and output documents. What result did you get?